# How do I .group and .sum in a rails model using Postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I have a functioning method in my development environment (SQLite) that looks this:

```
def self.ytd
Production.find(
    :all,
    conditions: ["year == ?", Time.now.year],
    select: "carrier_id, amount, SUM(amount) as sum_amount",
    group: :carrier_id
    )
end
```

This method successfully searches through a table consisting of `:carrier_id` and `:amount` columns.  It then sums the `:amount` column based on the grouped `:carrier_id`

I am trying to convert to a production environment using Postgresql.  The below code successfully groups the records however I cannot sum the `:amount`.  I have tried amending `.sum("productions.amount")` to the method without success.  I am sure there is a simple solution, but it alludes me.. can someone please help?  Thanks

```
def self.ytd
Production.select("DISTINCT ON (productions.carrier_id) productions.carrier_id, productions.amount ")
               .where("productions.year = (?)", "#{Time.now.year}")
               .group("productions.amount, productions.carrier_id, productions.id")
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed `DISTINCT ON`, added `SUM(amount) as sum_amount` and grouped on `:carrier_id` yielded the desired results.

```
def self.ytd
Production.select("productions.carrier_id, SUM(amount) as sum_amount")
               .where("productions.year = (?)", "#{Time.now.year}")
               .group("productions.carrier_id")      
end
```